# First row in one to many relationship join

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have 2 tables like this:

Table A:
guv, col1, col2

Table B:

guv, col3, col4, col5..

Now each A and B have one to many relationship, so when I run the following query:

```
select * from A,B where a.guv. = b.guv
```

It returns all the rows in B that match the join, how do I return only one row(based on some order in one of the columns) that matches?

I tried to do this using Top as read in some other answers, but its not supported by aws athena.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER()` function within the join query as the following:

```
SELECT guv, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM
(
 SELECT A.guv, A.col1, A.col2, B.col3, B.col4, B.col5,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.guv ORDER BY B.col3) rn 
 FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B
 ON A.guv=B.guv
) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

In `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.guv ORDER BY B.col3)` you may change the order by B.col3 to any other column order.

Comment: But i need the 1st row from every joined guv group! Not just the first row. That is, say Table A has 3 guvs g1,g2,g3 then i need 3 rows, which are the first rows of each of the rows that these guvs match in Table B

Comment: Yes, I understand you, the provided query gives you what you want. [Check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/voIkK1WQ)

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry i didnt explain the problem fully, so one more catch here is, i need to run this only for a part of guvs, so in the example, say i only want this run for guvs g1 and g2, where will i add that? if i add it after the inner join condition, that would be too large of a query to be run, because both these tables are massive

Comment: `WHERE A.guv IN ('g1', 'g2')` After the on clause in the join query.  [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/cRnpExYf)